# Whitespace being added at beginning of string when pasting into Eureka form | Swift

Tags: swift, textarea, eureka-forms

I have a Eureka form that displays a TextAreaRow. When the user attempts to "Paste" something from the UIPasteboard into this field, it adds a space to the front of the string (Example: "Homework" becomes " Homework" - notice the space at the front). How can I stop this from happening?

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class MyViewController: FormViewController {
   func setupEurekaForm() {
      form
      +++ Section("TEXTFIELDS")
      <<< TextAreaRow() {
         $0.value = "Test text"
         // here I need to somehow tell the field to disable smartInsertDeleteType
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to trim all leading spaces when the user pastes a string into your text field?

Comment: I guess that would be fine. Apple is just automatically adding a space at the front of the pasted string and I don't want it to do that.